# Creating equidistant points in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I am trying to create points (new layer) at specific distance along the road (existing layer) in QGIS. [Creating Regular points every meter at county level using ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13532)
 gives solution for ArcGIS. How to achieve this in QGIS? [Adding points to point vector layer using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23736) explains how to create points but does not do anything about the distance.

---

(I applied the proposed solutions with different measures of lengths for I did not know the conversion)
@Nathans's solution worked to some extent, I got...

[image].
Here, the projection of these equidistant points is different from the original line.

With @underdark's suggestion, I got

[image: this image] where the points does not seem to be equidistant. I guess there is some projection issue with both of these which I am not understanding.

Comment: Compare http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11992/how-to-create-a-point-along-a-line-given-distance

Comment: A couple of points. Firstly, the line has to be in a projected CRS (not lat/lon). Secondly, is your line a true polyline? I don't think any method will work properly on a line comprising a string of individual lines. Nick.

Comment: Also with my code, you don't need to call the `import locate` line more then once. Just call it once then you can call `locate.pointsAlongLine(30)` as much as you need

Comment: Another method (given that Sextant as suggested by some answers here is QGIS <2.0 only), is also to use the plugin called QChainage.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Note:** There is now a QGIS plugin `QChainage`.  It does all this and more. The code below is out of date with QGIS 2.0 and above.

Here is some Python code that you can stick in a file and use inside QGIS:

QGIS does have a method in it API to do liner referencing however I couldn't get it to work correctly, but I will contact the author of the code and see if I was doing something wrong.

For now you will need the **shapely** Python library, which you should install anyway because it's handy to have around.  It also has great documentation at http://toblerity.github.com/shapely/manual.html

This is the section I am using in the following example http://toblerity.github.com/shapely/manual.html#interoperation.

Most of the following code is QGIS boilerplate code just creating the features, layers, converting from wkb and wkt and back.  The core bit is the `point = line.interpolate(currentdistance)` which returns a point at a distance along a line.  We just wrap this in a loop until we run out of line.

```
import qgis
from qgis.core import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import QVariant
from shapely.wkb import loads
from shapely.wkt import dumps

vl = None
pr = None

def createPointsAt(distance, geom):
    if distance > geom.length():
        print "No Way Man!"
        return

    length = geom.length()
    currentdistance = distance
    feats = []  

    while currentdistance < length: 
        line = loads(geom.asWkb())
        point = line.interpolate(currentdistance)
        fet = QgsFeature()
        fet.setAttributeMap( { 0 : currentdistance } )
        qgsgeom = QgsGeometry.fromWkt(dumps(point))
        fet.setGeometry(qgsgeom)
        feats.append(fet)
        currentdistance = currentdistance + distance

    pr.addFeatures(feats)
    vl.updateExtents()

def pointsAlongLine(distance):
    global vl
    vl = QgsVectorLayer("Point", "distance nodes", "memory")
    global pr
    pr = vl.dataProvider()  
    pr.addAttributes( [ QgsField("distance", QVariant.Int) ] )
    layer = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().currentLayer()
    for feature in layer.selectedFeatures():
        geom = feature.geometry()
        createPointsAt(distance, geom)

    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vl)
```

Copy and paste the above code into file, I called my locate.py, in `~./qgis/python` directory (because it is in the Python path) and just do the this in the Python console inside QGIS.

```
 import locate
 locate.pointsAlongLine(30)
```

That will create a new point layer with points at every 30 meters along the selected lines, like so:

[image]

***Note: Code is pretty rough and might need some clean up.***

**EDIT: The lastest QGIS dev build can now do this natively.**

Change the while loop in `createPointsAt` to:

```
 while currentdistance < length: 
    point = geom.interpolate(distance)
    fet = QgsFeature()
    fet.setAttributeMap( { 0 : currentdistance } )
    fet.setGeometry(point)
    feats.append(fet)
    currentdistance = currentdistance + distance
```

and you can remove the

```
from shapely.wkb import loads
from shapely.wkt import dumps
```

Comment: Thanks @Nathan. I could not get the Shapely package for my python. I installed python 2.7 but Shapely installer says that python 2.7 is not in my registry. Is there another way to install Shapely.

Comment: I followed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652625/installing-setuptools-on-64-bit-windows and typed the above two lines for calling `locate` and using it but still I did not get the equidistant points. Also, I am a neophyte in Python so I did not understand where to run the code (1) python in qgis directory or (2) that at C:\Python27\?

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: Windows 7 Professional

Comment: create the python file in `C:\Users\{you user name}\.qgis\python` then restart QGIS if open, and go to ` Plugins-> Python Console`.  Load a line layer, select a line a call `import locate` and `locate.pointsAlongLine(30)`

Comment: You might have to use the OSGeo4W install of QGIS to make this work correctly

Comment: great method Nathan, thx. In combination with your plugin "switch direction of a polyline" you even can change the start and endpoint of these points.

Comment: Can't seem to get this to work - QGIS API changes? Fails at `setAttributeMap`!

Comment: Use the QChainage plugin.  It does everything you need using the new API.

Comment: do you have a version for qgis 3x ?

Answer (score 5):

You could use the QGIS GRASS plugin v.to.points tool to create points along lines at regular intervals

```
# convert line to points; dmax = distance between points
v.to.points -i -v -t in=road out=road_pts type=line dmax=90
```

Comment: I used dmax as 100 and the resultant projections for each is as follows. (I do not know how the CRS is getting assigned by itself. ) `CRS of Original Shape file, the line = EPSG:26915 - NAD83 / UTM zone 15N,
CRS of Grass line vector obtained using v.in.ogr = EPSG:4269 - NAD83,
CRS of Grass points vector obtained using v.to.points = EPSG:4326 - WGS 84`

Comment: Now also like this: QGIS -> Sextante -> GRASS -> v.to.points

Answer (score 5):

If you want to plot the chainage at fixed intervals along a road line you could use the 'Profile from line' plug-in to do this. You need a DEM under the road line layer, but the procedure is quick and very simple. Nick.

[image]

Comment: this is a pretty good and easy method too, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Beware that the Shapely (Python) / GEOS (C++) data model is defined in a plane. So if your points consist of GPS positions (latitude, longitude) using the `shapely.geometry.LineString.interpolate(distance)` method will output a GPS position at the euclidean distance along the given `LineString`.

Shapely's `interpolate()` is based on GEOS' `geos::linearref::LengthIndexedLine` class using the `extractPoint` method.

Supposedly the equally spaced interpolation in the latitude-longitude-plane is sufficient for applications considering relatively small distances. In general, however, one should consider the distance on a sphere for GIS applications (as defined in [WGS84](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System#A_new_World_Geodetic_System:_WGS_84)).

I can think of two workarounds using the Shapely module:

- `LineString` properties are all given points and linearly-interpolated curves along them. Perhaps you can write a member which accesses the interpolated curves and implement the following line integral substituting the euclidean distance. I fancy this approach because using the piece-wise continuous curve the desired points can be obtained by calculating the intersections of adjacent circles along the curve with the radius  `r = radian_measure(arc_length) = arc_length / R`, where R equals Earths' radius at the given position.
- code your own interpolation method (without touching Shapely code) using an appropriate distance function (eg. haversine formula).

To achieve this I would like refer to the following [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19117660) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19118984) in particular:

> It IS possible to generate equidistant points along the curve. But
>   there must be more definition of what you want for a real answer.
>   Sorry, but the code I've written for this task is in MATLAB, but I can
>   describe the general ideas. There are three possibilities.
>
> First, are the points to be truly equidistant from the neighbors in
>   terms of a simple Euclidean distance? To do so would involve finding
>   the intersection at any point on the curve with a circle of a fixed
>   radius. Then just step along the curve.
>
> Next, if you intend distance to mean distance along the curve itself,
>   if the curve is a piecewise linear one, the problem is again easy to
>   do. Just step along the curve, since distance on a line segment is
>   easy to measure.
>
> Finally, if you intend for the curve to be a cubic spline, again this
>   is not incredibly difficult, but is a bit more work. Here the trick is
>   to:
>
> - Compute the piecewise linear arclength from point to point along the    curve. Call it t. Generate a pair of cubic splines, x(t), y(t).
> - Differentiate x and y as functions of t. Since these are cubic    segments, this is easy. The derivative functions will be piecewise
>     quadratic.
> - Use an ode solver to move along the curve, integrating the    differential arclength function. In MATLAB, ODE45 worked nicely.
>
> Thus, one integrates
>
> ```
> sqrt((x')^2 + (y')^2)
> ```
>
> Again, in MATLAB, ODE45 can be set to identify those locations where
>   the function crosses certain specified points.
>
> If your MATLAB skills are up to the task, you can look at the code in
>   [interparc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19118984) for more explanation. It is reasonably well commented
>   code.
>
> [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19118984):
>   http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34874-interparc

Answer (score 1):

Sextante has a tool that might work for you. Sextante can be downloaded from the Qgis plugin repository.
Look for: 
"Tools for Line Layers"
"Lines to equispaced points"

Comment: This plugin doesn't seem to be available for QGIS 2 or 3.