# Densifying polyline according to specific length using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, geometry, polyline-creation, densify

I am using QGIS 1.8.0
I would like to densify a polyline according to a particular length of segment (ex. 200 m). I know it is possible with other GIS software.

Is it possible to do this in QGIS?

Comment: Am I right assuming that you are not looking for buffers? Do you want to insert new vertices ever e.g. 200 meters?

Comment: @undermak. Yes you are right, sorry if I did not explain the problem correctly. I need to inserti vertices every 200 meteres.

Comment: Densify in Qgis appears to add a 1...n number of vertices to each line segment.  In longer than 200m or shorter than 200m segments, the resolution would multiply, but not respect the specific length portion of the question as asked.  Maybe http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27102/how-to-create-equidistant-points-in-qgis is relevant, but it doesn't change the set of vertices along the lines.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible.  Densify is located under the vector menu.

http://woostuff.wordpress.com/2012/06/21/qgis-1-8-is-out/

Answer (score -1):

I assume what you mean by densify is effectively a buffer, where the line thickness is proportional to a function of the line length.

This can be achieved using a small amount of scripting. I am unable to write the script at present as I have no access to QGIS, however the pseudocode will be along the lines of:

```
FOR each polyline:
    buffersize = line_length * constant
    BUFFER polyline by buffersize
```

Comment: Densify means adding intermediate points along the line, not making a buffer.