# Generating points along a GPX line with 3D distance intervals

Tags: point, line, gps, gpx, tracking

I recently tracking the road using *Garmin GPS*, I get the tracking line which is in GPX format. The file has CRS *EPSG:4326*

Now, I want to make point with specific interval (100 m) along the line. I know *QGIS* has "`point along geometry`" tool. But we must project it to UTM and it makes points with 100 m interval

[image: Point along geometry tool in QGIS]

The problem is.. *QGIS* calculate interval between point in 2D cartesian (projected) **instead**  calculate the interval based on real interval (the road is up and down and its altitude already stored in GPX)

How do I make point along line with specific interval (100 m) which calculate the up and down of the track?

I welcome for any way to do it (for example with *GeoPandas, shapely, GRASS*, etc)

EDITED:

[suggested answers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27102/creating-equidistant-points-in-qgis)

It differs with that link. I want real distance which calculate XYZ of the road

Comment: Interesting question!  Can you supply a link to your GPX data so that others can test it?

Comment: @Hornbydd QChainage plugin give me same result with QGIS "point along geometry". It make point base on projected layer (2D cartesian)